# jQuery is Refreshing the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with JQuery: whenever a JQuery function is called, the page refreshes whenever an if block is executed.

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    removeOption($(this));
});

function removeOption(obj){
if (obj.parent().siblings().size() > 1){
    obj.parent().remove();
}
}
```

IF the (obj.parent()...) block is executed, the page refreshes. It's not limited to the function: if I change the if (obj.parent()... ) to if (true), I have the same problem. I also have the problem if I put the removeOption(obj) as an anonymous function inside the first function. Could this be a bug in JQuery, or does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Is it an `a` tag with the class of `.remove`?

Comment: There's no way that code that would refresh the page, your just missing a preventDefault() in your click handler, and clicking the button, anchor or whatever it is refreshes the page as the default action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
    removeOption($(this));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Se @Anas reply to for an explanation on the behaviour

Comment: @MattStern, note the up-votes on the other answer by Anas.  You should really be using `preventDefault` rather than `return false` and Anas deserves the checkmark IMO.

Answer (score 6):

When you handle link click on jquery, you must disable the default behviour.

By clicking on a link, you jquery event is raised, then removeOption($(this)) is called; but you must stop the default behavior so we use :

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
   removeOption($(this));
   return false;
});
```

at the end.

An other method is to call preventDefault ( http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ )  method like this :

```
 $(".remove").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   removeOption($(this));
 });
```

Anas,

Comment: Probably don't want `return false;` since that stops propagation too. The better answer is `e.preventDefault` as you have it